# Why don't I get the Tumbleweed badge?

Tags: support, badges, tumbleweed-badge

I have been waiting for the Tumbleweed badge for weeks for one of the question I asked, but haven't gotten it so far. The question was asked on Oct 21, 2016, and has received just 19 views so far and zero answers.

Why doesn't Stack Overflow give me my badge?

Comment: I have not provided a link to the question in an attempt to not increase the view count :D

Comment: It's really not hard to find it, especially since you told us when it was asked...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *think* I know which one you're talking about.  The reason you're not getting a badge:  it has a comment on it.

[Per the badge rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/175248), the question can't have *any* comments on it in addition to less than 60 views and no answers.

Comment: Did not know that my own comment counted

Comment: @FlyingGambit:  It's still a comment...

Comment: The badge almost tempts me to ask the worst possible question ever

Comment: @FlyingGambit:  Please don't.  It wouldn't be good for your continued participation here.

Comment: @FlyingGambit that idea will backfire. It takes a lot of luck, but essentially you need to ask a question so completely uninteresting that no one wants look at it. A bad question will attract attention because people will want to download our close it.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Aha thanks, I understand now, I need to ask a good question but completely uninteresting to anyone

Comment: @FlyingGambit Please don't ask a question in the sole effort to get a badge, ask questions because you need help, not been asked before, researched, has an MCVE etc

Comment: @FlyingGambit: maybe try deleting your own comment (especially if it's not too relevant or if you include the info in the answer)? If the badge award logic is re-executed you may still get it...

Comment: @DanCornilescu:  The post still has to have a score of 0.  I don't believe it does.